# Winlogbeat - not streaming logs

Tags: active-directory, filebeat

I am trying to stream my active directory logs ("Active Directory Web Services", "Directory Services") to a Winlogbeat but it is not working. This is my winlogbeat.yml file

```
   winlogbeat.event_logs:
      - name: Application
        ignore_older: 6h
      - name: Security
        ignore_older: 6h
      - name: System
        ignore_older: 6h
      - name: HardwareEvents
        ignore_older: 6h
      - name: Windows PowerShell
        ignore_older: 6h
      - name: Active Directory Web Services
        ignore_older: 6h
      - name: Directory Service
        ignore_older: 6h
    output.logstash:
      enabled: true
      hosts: ["data.acme.com:5044"]
      ssl.enabled: true
      ssl.certificate_authorities: ["${path.home}\\acme.cer"]
```

All of the other ones are streaming properly. Im thinking that is has something to do with the location of the other directory logs but i dont know how to tell winlogbeat to look at the correct location. Using Filebeat isnt an option due to it not rendering the evtx file properly.